# Lenovo W510 won't resume from sleep with second hard drive installed

Tags: windows-7, sleep, thinkpad

I have a 128GB SSD in place of the original hard drive and the old hard drive, a 160GB HDD in the Ultrabay with a third party adapter. Running Windows 7 Enterprise. This problem does not happen when I don't have the 160GB HDD in the Ultrabay

When I put the computer in sleep mode and then try to resume, the fan powers up, but the power light keeps slowly blinking as if it were still in sleep mode. The only way to get it back running is to do a hard reset, and the only way to avoid the problem is to not have the second hard drive installed.

Things I've tried:

- Closed lid, removed drive, tried to resume
- Closed lid, removed and reinserted drive, tried to resume
- Updated BIOS to v1.45
- Made sure SSD is first boot priority in BIOS
- Removed all USB devices and tried to resume